# I don't understand what is wrong with my logic that is making some of my output come out correct and incorrect

Tags: c

when I call this print function in a loop from i<6, the first two outputs for the strings only (time and location) come out incorrect or blank, and I don't understand why since they are correct the rest of the time. Am I forgetting a simple reinitialization of a variable somewhere? Sorry for any poor formatting, as I'm new to programming in general.

```
void print_data(int i, equake_t e[][800], int size, FILE *pointer)
{
    int j = 0;
    double max3=0, date1=0;
    double date2=0, date3=0;
    char jay=0;

    max3=e[i][0].magnitude;     
    date1=e[i][0].timestamp.day;
    date2=e[i][0].timestamp.month;
    date3=e[i][0].timestamp.year;
    jay=0;
    j=0;

    while(j<size)
    {
        if(e[i][j].magnitude>max3)
        {
            max3=e[i][j].magnitude;
            date1=e[i][j].timestamp.day;
            date2=e[i][j].timestamp.month;
            date3=e[i][j].timestamp.year;
            jay=j;
        }
        j++;
    }
    fprintf(pointer,"Largest Magnitude of %.1lf occurred on %.0f/%.0f/%.0f %s at %s\n", max3, date2, date1, date3, e[i][jay].timestamp.time, e[i][jay].location);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't even decided yet *which* code is not working for you, hence the edits. Come back with an MCVE, when decided. VTC.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It is hard to know what might be going wrong — but the chances are moderately high that the trouble is outside this function.  Using `double` values for the components of a date is pretty weird.  An MCVE is unlikely to use 800 as the second dimension of the array; 8 might be appropriate, but a still smaller number like 4 might be better still.

Comment: Difficult to know for sure since you haven't provided a [MCVE], but posted code has UB, since `%lf` is not a valid conversion specifier; should be `%f` to match corresponding `double` value `max3`.

Comment: You have potential for major headaches because you use `int j = 0;` and `char jay = 0;` but then copy `j` to `jay`.  The types should be the same — and both `int` if you might need to go up to `800` elements in the row of the 2D array.  It might be better to insulate the function from the 2D-ness of the array.  You could write `void print_data(equake_t e[], int size, FILE *pointer)` and then simply call it with `print_data(quake_list[i], size, fp)` (instead of `print_data(i, quake_list, size, fp)` using your current code).

Comment: @DavidBowling: C99 permits `%lf` as a synonym for `%f`; C90 did not.

Comment: @DavidBowling: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.6.1 **The `fprintf` function** ¶7 says: _`l` (ell) — Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a
`long int` or `unsigned long int` argument; that a following `n`
conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `long int` argument; that a
following `c` conversion specifier applies to a `wint_t` argument; that a
following `s` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `wchar_t`
argument; or has no effect on a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler-- I knew this sounded familiar as soon as you said it, but despite being right in front of me, I couldn't see it! The connection between my eyes and brain is sketchy when I need to eat....

Comment: @DavidBowling: nearly as bad as being under-caffeinated :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler-- yes. Food now, maybe caffeine later!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:  Thanks so much! I don't know how the char type for jay blew by me, changing it to int solved the problem! Sorry about the lack of MCVE, I'll try to work on that for the next time I post on here.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*Transferring what turns out to be an accurate diagnosis from comment into answer.*</sup>

You have potential for major headaches because you use `int j = 0;` and `char jay = 0;` but then copy `j` to `jay`. The types should be the same — and both `int` if you might need to go up to 800 elements (or, in fact, any number more than 127) in the row of the 2D array.

---

Tangentially, it might be better to insulate the function from the 2D-ness of the array. You could write:

```
void print_data(equake_t e[], int size, FILE *pointer)
```

and then simply call it with:

```
print_data(quake_list[i], size, fp)
```

(instead of using `print_data(i, quake_list, size, fp)` with your current function signature).  This also has benefits if you ever need to change from 800 to a larger or smaller value; your called code doesn't need to change, though the calling code would need the new array size.